# Eclipse Kepler: How to share an existing project to an existing remote Git repo?

Tags: eclipse, git

I currently Eclipse Kepler on my new computer with EGit. And I have a particular project on it, not linked to any repository.

Now there is a remote Git repository (with all the account and password information at hand) someone else created for me and I want to push this project onto it. Since I never used Git on eclipse before, I figured it may be somehow similar to my limited experience with CVS - so I tried: `right click -> team -> share project -> Git` (I read somewhere that I should select the "remote" option, but there is no such option besides "share project" and "Apply Patch"), but it only shows the local clone of the Git repository, and if I tried to add the project to it it tells me that "cannot move project to target location as location overlaps..." So now I am stuck and not sure what to do, can anyone help me find the right direction?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so you already have a local repository of this project (connected to the remote server) ? and another copy into your workspace ?

Comment: @flafoux I have a local git clone of this repository, but the project was created before I gained access to the repository, and it was not in any local or remote repository.

Comment: Then you should import project in your eclipse from the local repository. If you have change made in your workspace, you should take a copy somewhere, delete it and find a way to manually report change in the newly imported project.